# Update property in a component from parent-child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In the root of my Application I have a Header component that contains an image. The root also contains a Page component which holds different content based on the Route.

The Header component has a property named HeaderImage (url) and I'd like to be able to update the HeaderImage (url) from the Page component.

Can anyone suggest a good approach, I was thinking of just adding some logic to the Header component that switched the HeaderImage (url) based on the Route but I'd like a little more flexibility. I'd ideally like to be able to update the image from the Page component children.

Comment: Using redux store seems to be good option

Answer (score 0):

You can Pass the url to root and let root update it for Header using props like :

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state={
        urlForHeader : null
      }

      this.updateUrl = this.updateUrl.bind(this);
    }

    function updateUrl(url){
      this.setState({
        urlForHeader : url
      })
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          url={this.state.urlForHeader}
        />
        <PageContent
          updatingFunction={this.updateUrl}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to implement componentWillUpdate in your component, see this docs about it.

[React js ComponentWillUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)